# Instagram API pagination: data redundancy

Tags: pagination, instagram, instagram-api

I called Instagram API for recent media for a certain hashtag. In side of the response, there is a pagination and a field `next_url`. I used this url to call for the next media, but then I found out that there were the redundancy media, with the same `id`. So I wanna ask, is there anyway to call for the api, but with no redundancy? Because as the way Instagram describe there API, I think that having the redundancy is unlikely to happen.